# Photoshop cut command is disabled

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

I don't understand why I cannot cut image in Photoshop. The cut command is disabled. I'm sure that I have selected the image. I can copy and paste, but just not cut.

[image]

Comment: Is it your locked background layer?

Comment: @Scott No, the image is on a separate layer.

Comment: Is it a Smart Object?

Comment: General advice for asking troubleshooting questions about Photoshop: always include a screenshot of the relevant part of your layers palette. Without it, answerers are reduced to shooting in the dark like what happened here. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for your suggestion. I will next time!

Comment: @Wolff Yes it is a smart object. I didn't know that smart object cannot be cut. Once I rasterize it and make a selection. I can then cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to cut you need to make sure:

1. layer is not locked
2. layer is not smart object. generally, needs to be a raster layer (no vector shapes)
3. you need to have something selected (i don't see anything selected in your image)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes. the image is a smart object and it cannot be cut. Once I rasterized it, I can then make a selection and cut it. It also seems that I cannot cut the whole layer (unlike that I can copy the whole layer).

Answer (score 2):

you can not cut from a Smart Object layer, you can copy, just can not cut. Have to rasterize it to cut.
Similar problem: If you can not cut AS WELL AS copy a selection, you must be working on a shape, and still, you got to rasterize it.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your layer is a smart object
try to right-click on your layer and click rasterize layer 
after then you could cut the photo.
be careful to duplicate your smart object layer because once you rasterize it 
it won't be a smart object again so be aware to have a copy of  the original once.